# How to replace with java lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

is it possible to replace construct with lambda:

```
DMXFrame[] frames = new DMXFrame[universes.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
   frames[i] = universes.get(i).getDMXFrame();
}

return frames;
```

Comment: What type is `universes`?

Answer (score 5):

Here it is, assuming `universes` is of type `Collection<Universes>`:

```
return universes.stream()
    .map(Universes::getDMXFrame)
    .toArray(DMXFrame[]::new)
```